# How to run official example of Haskell WebSockets library

Tags: haskell, websocket

According to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494922/examples-of-websocket-usage-in-haskell I have my first question. Why official example of WebSockets library doesn't run on my machine?

```
import Data.Char (isPunctuation, isSpace)
import Data.Monoid (mappend)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Exception (fromException)
import Control.Monad (forM_, forever)
import Control.Concurrent (MVar, newMVar, modifyMVar_, readMVar)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Network.WebSockets

meow :: TextProtocol p => WebSockets p ()
meow = forever $ do
    msg <- receiveData
    sendTextData $ msg `T.append` ", meow."

main :: IO ()
main = runServer "0.0.0.0" 8000 meow
```

I get:

```
ciembor@freedom ~> ghc hchat.hs; and ./hchat
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hchat.hs, hchat.o )

hchat.hs:15:35:
    Couldn't match expected type `Text' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the second argument of `T.append', namely `", meow."'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `msg `T.append` ", meow."'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: sendTextData $ msg `T.append` ", meow."

hchat.hs:18:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `Request -> WebSockets p0 ()'
                with actual type `WebSockets p1 ()'
    In the third argument of `runServer', namely `meow'
    In the expression: runServer "0.0.0.0" 8000 meow
    In an equation for `main': main = runServer "0.0.0.0" 8000 meow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is because you didn't enable the `OverloadedStrings` language extension. Without that, a `"xyz"` is a `String`, but `Data.Text.append` takes two `Text`s as arguments. Add

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
```

to the top of the module to fix that one.

The second error is because the third argument to `runServer` must have type

```
Request -> WebSockets p0 ()
```

but you gave it a `WebSockets p1 ()`. If you want to pass an action, you have to lift it to a function,

```
main = runServer "0.0.0.0" 8000 $ const meow
```

would compile (whether it would work [do what you want] is a question I cannot answer, that would just ignore all requests and always do the same thing).