# Simple Haskell WebSockets application -- connection is closed just after client starts (connection is ready, but not opened)

Tags: haskell, websocket

OK, this is continuation of this topic: [How to run official example of Haskell WebSockets library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521553). I want a server which will response to every client request in a loop.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Char (isPunctuation, isSpace)
import Data.Monoid (mappend)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Exception (fromException)
import Control.Monad (forM_, forever)
import Control.Concurrent (MVar, newMVar, modifyMVar_, readMVar)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Network.WebSockets

meow :: TextProtocol p => WebSockets p ()
meow = forever $ do
    msg <- receiveData
    sendTextData $ msg `T.append` ", meow."

app :: Request -> WebSockets Hybi00 ()
app _ = meow

main :: IO ()
main = runServer "0.0.0.0" 8000 app
```

Now I try to use it from JavaScript:

```
var socket;  
var host = "ws://localhost:8000";  
var socket = new WebSocket(host);  
    console.log("ready");  
    socket.onopen = function(){  
         console.log("open");  
         socket.send("cats do ");
    }  
    socket.onmessage = function(msg){  
         console.log("msg");  
    }  
    socket.onclose = function(){  
         console.log("close");  
    }
```

But connection is closed just after client starts (connection is ready, but not opened). I expected something else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [accept the request](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/latest/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html#v%3aacceptRequest) before you can start using the websocket connection. E.g.

```
app :: Request -> WebSockets Hybi00 ()
app req = do
    acceptRequest req
    meow
```